# Two columns in text area or option pane

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, joptionpane

I need to make two column for instance:

```
Item Name          Item Price          Item ID
Hello              42.25               10041
Another Item       822.00              12405
...                ...                 ...
```

Is there any thing I could to to make two columns? It can be either on a `JTextArea` or inside `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog`.

Comment: I think you need to use a [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) instead.  You're only other option might be to use a `JLabel` formatted with a `html` table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something you can do like this

```
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder() ;
        builder.append("<html><table border=1><tr><td>Item Name</td><td>Item Price</td><td>Item Code</td></tr>");
        for( Item item_ : itemList ) {
            builder.append("<tr><td>");
            builder.append(item_.getItemName());
            builder.append("</td><td>");
            builder.append(item_.getItemPrice());
            builder.append("</td><td>");
            builder.append(item_.getItemID());
            builder.append("</td></tr>");
        }
        builder.append("</table></html>");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parentDialog,
                builder.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html), Because It's better to use

But, Even though You want to do this, You can do this as

```
jTextArea.setText("Items Name\t\tItem Price\t\tItem ID\n");  
jTextArea.append("Hello\t\t42.25\t10041\t\t?\n");  
jTextArea.append("Another Item\t\t822.00\t\t12405\t?\n");
```

Comment: but if text goes beyond its allotted column, you're in deep trouble.

Comment: +1 its an idea but it wont help always if content exceeds long.

Comment: You'll also have problems if the user's fonts are variable width